# Overlapping flutter widgets in a column

Tags: flutter, layout

I have a column containing an expanded map on top and a card on the bottom showing some information. This card has a border-radius so without any change I would have an unpleasant empty space around the corners of the card:

[image]

My current solution to this is to put the map inside Transform.scale which is a hacky way to cover that space. I am wondering if maybe there is a more preferred solution to this?

I tried to use stack but my problem with stack was that if my card size changed then the positioned map would have to know about that change to adjust its bottom accordingly which resulted in a messy code.

Edit:
This is my current solution that i am looking for a way to improve.

```
Column(
  children: [
    Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.1,
      child: MapView(),
    ),
    const Card()
   ],
 )
```

Comment: please provide your code snippet to understand better.

Comment: @ShahedEmon I've included a code snippet of my existing solution. I'm seeking an improved approach that incorporates a fixed overlap (e.g., an additional 16px in height) instead of being relative to the current size of the map.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of it is CLipRRect and Stack widget. ClipRRect is a little hard to understand but if you did it you can solve this problem

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: MapView(),
    ),
    ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0), // Adjust the values as needed
        topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
      ),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white, // You can set the background color if needed
        child: const Card(), // Your card widget
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: ClipRRect does add a border-radius but what I am looking for here is that the map would go under the card for like 20 px so the white space around the rounder corner would be filled with map. this can not be achieved by the suggested snippet.